# Assigning same datasource to multiple DropDownLists?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to assign same datasource to multiple DropDownLists in a form, when the page loads, only the first drop down list has filled the content of datasource, others are empty, what's the missing point? thanks for answers. Here are the codes;

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">    
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="panel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
     <div id="div1" align="center">
      <table>
       <tr>
         <td><b>Brand-Model</b></td>
         <td><asp:TextBox ID="brandText" runat="server" BorderStyle="Inset"></asp:TextBox></td>
         <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="brandText" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td><b>Black</b></td>
         <td><asp:DropDownList ID="blackList" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
         <td><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text="Add Cartridge" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/addCartridge.aspx"></asp:HyperLink></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td><b>Color1</b></td>
         <td><asp:DropDownList ID="colorList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
       </tr> 
       <tr>
         <td><b>Color2</b></td>
         <td><asp:DropDownList ID="colorList2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td><b>Color3</b></td>
         <td><asp:DropDownList ID="colorList3" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td><b>Other1</b></td>
         <td><asp:DropDownList ID="otherColor1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td><b>Other2</b></td>
         <td><asp:DropDownList ID="otherColor2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td><b>Other3</b></td>
         <td><asp:DropDownList ID="otherColor3" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td><asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="submit_OnClick" /></td>       
       </tr>            
       <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td><asp:Label ID="submitInfo" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>       
       </tr>
      </table>
     </div>
    </ContentTemplate> 
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="submit" EventName="Click" />   
    </Triggers>   
   </asp:UpdatePanel> 
</form>
```

---

```
protected void FillTheDropDownLists()
    {
        SqlApplication con = new SqlApplication();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT name FROM BT.dbo.Cartridge ORDER BY name", con.GetConnection());
            con.OpenSqlConnection();

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            blackList.DataValueField = "name";
            blackList.DataSource = reader;
            blackList.DataBind();

            colorList1.DataValueField = "name";
            colorList1.DataSource = reader;
            colorList1.DataBind();

            colorList2.DataValueField = "name";
            colorList2.DataSource = reader;
            colorList2.DataBind();

            colorList3.DataValueField = "name";
            colorList3.DataSource = reader;
            colorList3.DataBind();

            otherColor1.DataValueField = "name";
            otherColor1.DataSource = reader;
            otherColor1.DataBind();

            otherColor2.DataValueField = "name";
            otherColor2.DataSource = reader;
            otherColor2.DataBind();

            otherColor3.DataValueField = "name";
            otherColor3.DataSource = reader;
            otherColor3.DataBind();

            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + err.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.CloseSqlConnection();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its becasue you are using dataReader instead of this use datatable will work for you. Reader is readonly and forward only thats why only first dropdonw get filled with data and others are  empty.

changed code :

```
protected void FillTheDropDownLists()
    {
        SqlApplication con = new SqlApplication();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT name FROM BT.dbo.Cartridge ORDER BY name", con.GetConnection());
            con.OpenSqlConnection();

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader );

            blackList.DataValueField = "name";
            blackList.DataSource = dt ;
            blackList.DataBind();

            colorList1.DataValueField = "name";
            colorList1.DataSource = dt ;
            colorList1.DataBind();

            colorList2.DataValueField = "name";
            colorList2.DataSource = reader;
            colorList2.DataBind();

            colorList3.DataValueField = "name";
            colorList3.DataSource = dt ;
            colorList3.DataBind();

            otherColor1.DataValueField = "name";
            otherColor1.DataSource = dt ;
            otherColor1.DataBind();

            otherColor2.DataValueField = "name";
            otherColor2.DataSource = dt ;
            otherColor2.DataBind();

            otherColor3.DataValueField = "name";
            otherColor3.DataSource = dt ;
            otherColor3.DataBind();

            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + err.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.CloseSqlConnection();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it has worked, but this time there is another problem, after posting the form, every selected value is the first value of content. It does not select the really selected value. Where can be problem?

Comment: check the view state property because i think its not holding state after post back

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) data reader is forward only. Use data table or read into a list and bind your combos to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= 260; i++)
        {
            ContentPlaceHolder maincontent = Page.Master.FindControl("MainContent") as ContentPlaceHolder;
            DropDownList a = (DropDownList)maincontent.FindControl("ddl" + i);



            a.DataSource = ds;
            a.DataTextField = "Options";
            a.DataValueField = "id";
            a.DataBind();
            a.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "0", true));
        }
```